# FLASK AZURE SQL DB - Queries running very slowly

Tags: flask, azure-sql-database

I've designed a small Flask app connected to a Azure SQL database. Everything worked just fine when I was testing with a small dataset, but now that I'm using the full database it became very slow. The thing is that the database is very small, only 3717 rows in this particular query (which is the biggest).
I'm wondering how I could improve the rendering of this query which runs in 1 second on Azure and between 40 secondes to 1 min on Flask (locally).
I've looked around but couldn't find a solution.

Some details :

- The query does a simple left join and results in 3717 rows and uses raw sql
- Results are being render in a bootstrap table showing only 10 results by default (filter in the upper left)
- Azure SQL db  : paid plan 250Go ~15eur/month
- I've tried caching using "flask_caching" but it doesn't improve
- Would this be resolved if I host the app using a paid plan on Azure app or is it not corrolated ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually managed to find a solution inspired by CairoCoders.
The problem was that the query returned all results at once on the page.

Here is a was to do it on with AJAX:

[Flask AJAX Datatables](https://tutorial101.blogspot.com/2021/04/datatable-ajax-pagination-using-python.html)

or using pagination (SQLAlchemy):

[Flask SQLAlchemy pagination](https://tutorial101.blogspot.com/2020/03/python-flask-sqlalchemy-pagination.html)